# Error While Trying to install create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, git, create-react-app, npm-install, npm-scripts

[image: thats the error in the image]I have been trying it now for the past minutes... I uninstall it and try again same error, I also install the latest version of node still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this command before installing `react-app`:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

If above doesn't work:

```
npm cache verify
```